# How to retrieve records before and after a certain recorder with Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I'm using the custom Query of Spring Repository. I can create custom method like this:

```
List<Order> findTop1ByOrderByCreateDateTimeDesc();
```

To get the most recent order.

But how do I get the previous and next order of a specific order sorted by CreateDateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two JPQL queries will return orders with closest createDateTime to specified.

Previous order:

```
select o from Order o where o.createDateTime = (select max(prev.createDateTime) from Order prev where prev.createDateTime < :specificOrderCreateDateTime)
```

Next order:

```
select o from Order o where o.createDateTime = (select min(next.createDateTime) from Order next where next.createDateTime > :specificOrderCreateDateTime)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without JPQL? Just by using the custom methods?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use query creation from method names. But you can use named query: ```@NamedQuery```. Or ```@Query``` in the spring repository.